# Nodejs : Error get/response localhost

Tags: node.js, cakephp, localhost, mamp

I'm running a Cakephp app with MAMP on localhost at port 80. I've also Node.js who listen/write on port 4000 with a js script from the Cake app (localhost/client).

When I call Node from js app, it works.

But, when I try to call a Cakephp page (localhost/saveData/123) from Node by http.get(); oder http.request for saving data in database, it crash.

> events.js:71
>           throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
>                          ^ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
>       at errnoException (net.js:770:11)
>       at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:761:19)

Oder

> problem with request: connect ECONNREFUSED

I've test width www.google.com, it works. It seems that's the problem is about "localhost".

Could someone help me? :)

EDIT : I've try with 127.0.0.1 too but it doesn't work (for MAMP and Node).

PS : sorry for my english, i'm french :)

Comment: I've try with MAMP on port 8888 and it works very well, it return a 200 code. I don't understand why a problem on port 80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have a local webserver running on port 80. Also programs like Skype can be connected to the port 80.

You can try close Skype and/or Webserver (XAMPP, WAMPP, usbwebserver, etc...).

Listing ports in Cmd.exe

> $ netstat -a

Comment: That is true ,its not beter to use port 80. Thats why most of the examples uses either 8080 or 8081